# Solr DataImportHandler using MySQL as source - dealing with json type columns

Tags: mysql, json, solr

I have a MySQL database with data collected from some crawling processes, now I'd like to replicate the data in a solr core to give them a better structure and being able to perform particular searches over them.

I've been able to use the *DataImportHandler* on my core, configuring a raw data-config.xml schema to import some of the columns in a single table, but before starting to deal with the other related entities I've to figure out how to solve a simple problem.

In many of my SQL tables I've got some columns where data was stored using MySQL's JSON type (yes, I should have used a no-sql from the beginning)

**Sample Data**

```
{
  "slug": "sample-item-slug",
  "Released": "2008",
  "Platforms": "Nintendo DS, PSP",
  "DevelopedBy": "Sample Developer",
  "PublishedBy": "Sample Publisher"
}
```

Id like to being able to import the keys in the json object as fields of my SOLR document.

How this can be done? I've looked at [Transformers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/DataImportHandler#DataImportHandler-Transformer), but seems that there is not a specific one for this purpose...

Can someone points me some suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you get to be the pioneer who writes the transformer to do this task. Or you could store your data in normal columns instead of JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately the data contained in those columns have several different keys and they may be different for every record, that's the reason why I've decided to use JSON at first sight

Comment: You should be able to use a [ScriptTransformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-scripttransformer) with `JSON.parse()` and then `row.put` the values you want from the JSON structure (or iterate over it at `row.put(key, value)` for each row from your JSON field).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my small problem, solutions are multiple

### Using [ScriptTransformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-scripttransformer)

As as sugested by @MatsLindh, probably the best way for cases when fields in the JSON column are dynamic, is to use a javascript function to transform the column data parsing it as a JSON string and iterating the resulting object for adding rows to the column data.

#### Example function fro ScriptTransformer

```js
function splitMetadata(row) {
  var metadata;
  metadata = JSON.parse(row.get('metadata'));
  if (metadata) {
    Object.keys(metadata).map(function(key, index) {
  row.put(key,metadata[key]);
    });
  }
  return row;
}
```

As [Solr Docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-scripttransformer) says, the `row` variable passed to the function is a `Java Map<String,Object>` type, so you can easily add data to it using `get,put,remove`.

#### Sample `data-config.xml` using ScriptTransformer

Based on the data model specified in the question, note that I've also used `RegexTransformer` to split a string in multiple values using a specified separator.

```xml
<entity name="metadata" query="select metadata from games" transformer="RegexTransformer,script:splitMetada">
    <field column="slug" name="attr_platforms" splitBy=" ," />
    <field column="Platforms" name="attr_platforms" splitBy=" ," />
    <field column="Released" name="release_date_dt" />
    <field column="DevelopedBy" name="developer_s" />
    <field column="DevelopedBy" name="publisher_s" />
</entity>
```

### Using MySQL Inline Path Operator `->>`

If you have a fixed number of json keys in your column you can just select them using MySQL's *Inline Path Operator*, to select specified keys in JSON columns, like this:

### Sample MySQL query

Based on the data model specified in the question

```sql
SELECT
metadata->>'$.Released' AS release_date,
metadata->>'$.Platforms' AS platforms,
metadata->>'$.DevelopedBy' AS developer, 
metadata->>'$.PublishedBy' AS publisher  
FROM games WHERE id='${game.ID}'
```

As the ScriptTransformer solution, you can declare you `metadata` column (the one that contains JSON in my case) as an `<entity>` in your `data-config.xml` file and handle it as a joined table, you can also create a `view` on your DB to avoid writing the query in the XML

#### Sample `data-config.xml` using MySQL query

Based on the query specified above

```xml
<entity name="metadata" query="select metadata->>'$.Released' as release_date,metadata->>'$.Platforms' as platforms,metadata->>'$.DevelopedBy' as developer, metadata->>'$.PublishedBy' as publisher  FROM games where id='${game.ID}'">
   <field column="release_date" name="release_date_dt" />
   <field column="platforms" name="attr_platforms" />
   <field column="developer" name="developer_txt" />
   <field column="publisher" name="publisher_txt" />
</entity>
```